# Powershell hasmoredata incorrect on windows 10 clean vs upgrade or older windows

Tags: windows, powershell

So i ran across a "bug" in Powershell in Windows 10. If you are on a clean install of Windows 10 this says NOT WORKING

```
$sb={$value = get-date}
$silent = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb
$silent = Get-Job | Wait-Job
if (Get-Job -HasMoreData $True){'NOT Working'}else{'Working'}
```

However if you are on an upgraded copy of Windows 10 this say WORKING as is Win 8 and Win 7

It would be nice if someone can verify this although i have played around with this a lot.
In addition what would be an easy method to code around this.
I have used this method to generate my list of machines that need code ran. Then I can just use the hasmoredata to run the code. This means all the Windows 10 boxes are false positives in old code.

Comment: I run the latest fast ring W10 build (upgraded 10+ times from RTM W10) and I get "NOT Working".

Comment: yep :( run it on 7/8/8.1/10_upgrade_from_7_or_8 and it will say "Working"

Comment: I can confirm this as well on Windows 10. When you run that job, it should have no output/data. `Get-Job` returns a job with `HasMoreData` equal to `$true`. When you send that job to `Receive-Job`, nothing is returned.

Comment: This has broken a lot of scripts for me :(